# unknown error exporting data from query studio

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to Export data in Contact Builder with Query Studio, but it moves me in an unknown error. Anyone can help me?[image]

Comment: It doesn’t appear you are currently logged into an account

Comment: I'm logged in on Marketing Cloud

Comment: What action triggers this? On what exactly do you click before you get this error?

Comment: If I click on "Export data" in query studio, It redirects me on the error

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a bug that has been [reported before](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A95yeSAB) and the issue could hide in tenant migration or any other actions that include moving your data.

Nevertheless, despite not working `Export in Contact Builder` button you can always find the `QueryStudioResults` folder under the root `Data Extensions` folder where you would find all results from your queries being accessible both in Contact Builder and Email Studio. It is exactly the same as what you would see if you clicked on `Export in Contact Builder` button and it would work, just takes another browser tab and couple more seconds of your time.

Take into consideration, that those Data Extensions with results are temporary and would be automatically deleted in 24 hours after you queried.